# Pandas read file lines as a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a corpus of text files (multiple txt files), each with the structure like:

```
TITLE: some title
URL: some url
META: some meta
DATE: some date
AUTHOR(S): author
TEXT: some text
```

How can I read the files, so that I have a dataframe with columns (title, url, ..., text)?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re` library to parse the text, for example ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DFAe27/1)):

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        dict(
            re.findall(
                r"^([A-Z][^:]+):\s*(.*?)\s*?(?=^[A-Z][^:]+:|\Z)",
                open("your_file.txt", "r").read(),
                flags=re.S | re.M,
            )
        )
    ]
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        TITLE       URL       META       DATE AUTHOR(S)       TEXT
0  some title  some url  some meta  some date    author  some text
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
import pandas as pd

paths = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']

content = []
for path in paths:
    with open(path) as f:
        content.append(tuple(map(lambda line: line.split(maxsplit=1)[1], 
                                 f.read().strip('\n').split('\n'))))

df = pd.DataFrame(content,
                  columns=['TITLE', 'URL', 'META', 'DATE', 'AUTHOR(S)', 'TEXT'])
```